# Authorization Required error when loading some pngs

Tags: javascript, three.js, apache2

So I'm having this weird issue. I have an apache2 server, behind a password wall using Auth. I have a page with a variety of resources being loaded. For some reason some of them give me this error and I can't figure out why.

Specifically, there are a number of pngs being loaded in the page. Some are simply in the DOM/HTML while others are inserted through javascript.

I'm using a library called Three.js for webgl and am using the function *loadTextureCube* which seems to be where the issue is, as all other images load.

I know I have the right credentials because I can access the site. I even made an exception for that folder and it still doesn't work

```
<Directory /path/to/imgs/folder>
    Options -Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This use to work before and now it doesn't for some reason

Comment: Is the page on the same server or are you doing CORS?